# What type of authentication should I use for Django with Flutter?

Tags: django, flutter

I am creating a Flutter project with Django + Django Rest framework as the backend. I want to add user authentication to the app.

I found some ways to achieve that such as Session authentication or token authentication. According to this [article](https://hackernoon.com/auth-headers-vs-jwt-vs-sessions-how-to-choose-the-right-auth-technique-for-apis-57e15edd053), if we want to add user authentication for mobile-based apps, it is best to use token authentication since session authentication is not suited for mobile phones.

Is it really best to use token authentication for mobile-based apps instead of session authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, token is best for mobile client.

Mobile and cookies are not good friends ;)

Token authentication work well for multiple device connection with same account and it's easier to store token.
It's stateless and work without cookies.

Comment: hi)) thank you for your kind comments. Look, I have two choices, either I need to use Token based authentication of Django Rest framework or JWT. Pls can you help which way is best to be used?

Comment: You can use both.

JWT is a standard defined by RFC 7519, so it allows better interoperability with the web ecosystem.

JWT is nothing more than an encrypted json document stored in a chain. Therefore, you can store additional data in the payload.

I advise you to take a look here https://jwt.io/

If you just want to have an identification token, go through Django token authentication.

If you want more or meet a standard, use JWT.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on two projects with Django and flutter.

I think for android or ios projects, token based authentication is best to go with because they are stateless and you can easily manage user roles and permissions for the application too.

From security point of view, it's also better because there's no possibility of creating a CSRF request when you app is using tokens.

Cookies don't fit much with other platform than a browser.